# Change property or apply event to multiple objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
var elem1 = $("#elem1");
var elem2 = $("#elem2");
var elem3 = $("#elem3");
```

I want to disable all these in single line of jquery code using the var names. I know jquery allows to find the multiple elements using single `$("#elem1, #elem2")` but I want to use the variable name and disable them at once, something like:

```
elem1.elem2.elem3.prop("disabled", true);
```

Is it possible? How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already have the objects selected, you can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
var elem1 = $("#elem1");
var elem2 = $("#elem2");
var elem3 = $("#elem3");

elem1.add(elem2).add(elem3).prop("disabled", true);
```

If you do not have the objects selected, you are better off using a class selector.

Comment: +1 both for being correct and for being the only person (so far) to actually provide what was asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [*attributes-starts-with* selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[id^="elem"]').prop('disabled',true);
```